# How to fix databinding errors in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors

I'm having an online Kotlin course. When I tried to apply the data binding part, I had some red errors in the .kt file.

The ActivityMainBinding is not imported so I did that manually,but the problem still persists.

here is the .kt :

```
package com.example.aboutme

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.Done_button).setOnClickListener { addNickname(it) }
    }
    private fun addNickname(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nickname_editText)
        val nicknameText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nickname_text)

        nicknameText.text = editText.text
        editText.visibility = View.GONE
        view.visibility = View.GONE
        nicknameText.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        //Hide the keyboard

        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)




    }
}
```

and here is the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <LinearLayout     android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
              android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding">

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/hanan_tabak"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:textAlignment="center" style="@style/name_style"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nickname_editText" style="@style/name_style" android:hint="@string/what_is_your_nickname"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nickname_text" style="@style/name_style"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Done_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:id="@+id/star_image" android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star" android:padding="8dp"/>
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/bio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scroll_text" style="@style/name_style"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"/>
    </ScrollView>
         </LinearLayout>
</Layout>
```

and here is the gradle.app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aboutme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding { enabled = true}
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.4.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

and here is gradle.project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The errors I face are:
1- In the line of code:

import com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding  :

(android) is in red font and the error is (Unresolved reference:android)

2- In this line of code:
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding  :

(ActivityMainBinding) is in red font and the error is ( Unresolved reference AcitivityMainBinding)

3- In this line of code:
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main):

there is a red underline under setContentView and the error says (Not enough information to infer variable T)

Comment: You forgot the most important part: **what is the error**?

Comment: Editted the post.

Comment: So, do you have a class named `com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`? The only class you posted is in the package `com.example.aboutme`. My guess is that it's the same for the other ActivityMainBinding.

Comment: you mean the import? what should be done then?

Comment: The code you posted uses the class `com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`. Your IDE tells you that this class doesn't exist. So, does it exist? If it doesn't, why are you using it?

Comment: I'm following the steps of the course.And even if I delete it, I'll still get red errors number 2,3 that I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and turned out it was a typo in my import. 
But I can see that is not the case with your issue. 
Although when I was searching for the answers I came across a question identical to yours asked by someone else. He apparently solved it by cleaning and rebuilding the project.

To do that go to `Build -> Clean Project` and then after that, `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Hope it works out!

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603328/android-in-kotlin-error-in-databinding-from-the-project-by-google-codelabs) to the other question if you want to check

Comment: I tried it,but it didn't work in this app...but it's funny that data binding worked fine in another app:)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in Android Studio with the invalidate cache and restart option in file menu

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout in this

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- YOUR LAYOUT HERE -->
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if still not working.
you can set viewbinding files in ' /build/generate/xxx '  as sources dir.
it is work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. The proper way to solve is to put this in build.gradle app.`buildFeatures{ dataBinding = true viewBinding = true }`